# Krajee Bootstrap file input dynamic maxFilecount

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I want to set `maxFileCount` with dynamic nums if input field changed.

My code:

```
<input value="" name="check_nums" class="check_nums">
```

krajee fileinput:

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    $('#file-th').fileinput({

        var check_nums = $(".check_nums").val();

        showUploadedThumbs: false,
        language: 'th',
        uploadAsync: false,
        maxFileCount: [check_nums],
        resizePreference: 'height',
        resizeImage: true,
        overwriteInitial: false,
        validateInitialCount: true,
        showUpload: false,

        allowedFileExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'],
        previewSettings: {
            image: {width: "auto", height: "100px"},
            object: {width: "213px", height: "160px"},
        },
        layoutTemplates: {
            actions: '<div class="file-actions">\n' +
                '    <div class="file-footer-buttons">\n' +
                '        {delete}' +
                '    </div>\n' +
                '</div>',
        }
    }).on("filebatchselected", function(event, files) {

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help:

First Change variable declaration position that is correct way to declare for initial stage.

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    var check_nums = $(".check_nums").val();
    $('#file-th').fileinput({
        showUploadedThumbs: false,
        language: 'th',
        uploadAsync: false,
        maxFileCount: check_nums, 
        resizePreference: 'height',
        resizeImage: true,
        overwriteInitial: false,
        validateInitialCount: true,
        showUpload: false,    
        allowedFileExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'],
        previewSettings: {
            image: {width: "auto", height: "100px"},
            object: {width: "213px", height: "160px"},
        },
        layoutTemplates: {
            actions: '<div class="file-actions">\n' +
                '    <div class="file-footer-buttons">\n' +
                '        {delete}' +
                '    </div>\n' +
                '</div>',
        }
    }).on("filebatchselected", function(event, files) {

    });
});
```

Then bind change event with input box and assign that input value as max limit for file input.

```
$(".check_nums").change(function(){
    $("#file-th").fileinput('maxFileCount',$(this).val());
});
```